# Not appear new documents in a repeat Control with searchs

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have 2 problems in a repeat control:

1) I have a repeat control with a search with querystring in "search in view results", like this:

```
if(viewScope.CLAVECEN != null & viewScope.CLAVECEN != "" & viewScope.CLAVECEN != "- Ver Todos -") {
     tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD centroautor = \"" + viewScope.CLAVECEN + "\")"; 
}


sessionScope.queryString = tmpArray;
```

This search run perfect normally, but when I create a new document and open this XPage doesn´t show the new documents.

I create the new document from other XPage and when I return to the XPage with repreat control doesn´t show the new documents. I guess that the repeat is Full refreh because I open the XPage.

I have tried the same but in a XPage with a repeat control in the same view without search
and works fine.

any idea?

2) In the same repeat control I have a Pager at the bottom and binding to the repeat control but the pager doesn´t refresh when the results change.
The structure is:

```
<xp:table id="repeatTable1">
   <xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{view2}" var="viewRow"                     
               indexVar="rowIndex" rows="200" repeatControls="true">
      ......................................................
   </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>  
<xp:pager id="pager1" layout="Previous Group Next"  
    panelPosition="bottom" for="repeat1">
</xp:pager>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) the search is based on a fulltext search which requires a fulltext index (see database properties -> tab with the magnifier). 
This index has a lag, new documents are not immediately in the index (even when the index properties are set to "immediate"). How fast the indexer updates the index depends on many factors like the work load of the Domino server.

Bottom line: new documents are not in the index immediately, therefore they are now displayed by your repeat control immediately. Allow a minute or so, then they should be visible.

2.) try wrapping the repeat and the pager into one panel and set the pager to do a partial update on that panel.

Maybe you need to force the repeat control to go to the first page after doing a search, see http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_views#Force+view+to+go+to+first+page for an example regarding views.

Comment: For the second problem with the pager, one question please. How is the way to say to the pager that the Partial refresh is ON the panel? because I can´t find that option. I have marked the option of "Partial refresh" on pager and doesn´t work. Thanks a lot Julian.